# Cannot read external table or read using utl_file.get_line on Windows 10 with Oracle 18c

Tags: oracle, external-tables

I just upgraded to Oracle 18c XE from 11g. I have an external table that worked fine on 11g, but I keep getting the following errors on 18c.

```
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-11604: no directory object specified for log file
```

The directory does exist and I have the correct grants.

```
SELECT *
FROM   all_directories
WHERE  directory_name = 'MYDIR';

OWNER  DIRECTORY_NAME  DIRECTORY_PATH  ORIGIN_CON_ID
SYS  MYDIR  C:\Users\sneuf\OneDrive\PLSQL\OracleDirectory  1
```

I have the required privileges.

```
SELECT * 
FROM all_tab_privs 
WHERE table_name = 'MYDIR' 
AND grantee = 'C##_SNEUF'; 
GRANTOR GRANTEE TABLE_SCHEMA TABLE_NAME PRIVILEGE GRANTABLE HIERARCHY COMMON TYPE INHERITED 
SYS     C##_SNEUF    SYS         MYDIR    EXECUTE      YES     NO       NO   DIRECTORY NO 
SYS     C##_SNEUF    SYS         MYDIR    READ         YES     NO       NO   DIRECTORY NO 
SYS     C##_SNEUF    SYS         MYDIR    WRITE        YES     NO       NO   DIRECTORY NO
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing a grant somewhere, but I can't figure out what. Can someone please help?

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE C##_SNEUF.CHECKING_TBL_EXT2 
   (  
  DB_KEY NUMBER, 
  CHECK_NUM VARCHAR2(10), 
  TRANS_DATE TIMESTAMP (6), 
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(100), 
  DEPOSIT_WITHDRAWAL VARCHAR2(1), 
  AMOUNT VARCHAR2(12), 
  MEMO VARCHAR2(200)
   ) 
   ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
    ( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
      DEFAULT DIRECTORY MYDIR
      ACCESS PARAMETERS
      ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    BADFILE MYDIR: 'checking.bad'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LDRTRIM
    MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
(
  DB_key CHAR,
  check_num CHAR(10),
  trans_date CHAR(21) DATE_FORMAT DATE MASK 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS',
  description CHAR(100),
  deposit_withdrawal CHAR(1),
  amount CHAR(12),
  memo CHAR(200)
            )
                     )
      LOCATION
       ( MYDIR: 'checking.csv'
       )
    )
   REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED ;
```

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: "no directory object specified **for log file**". So, how does the CREATE (external) TABLE look like? Any clue there?

Comment: Logfile isn't specified, so - by default - it resides in the same directory as the data file. However, as you **write** to log file, you require **write** privilege on the MYDIR directory. Info you posted suggests that you have only READ privilege so - try to grant WRITE as well.

Comment: Note that you'd have the same problem with the bad file-- that's going to default to using MYDIR so if you rejected a row, you'd also need to have write access on the directory.

Comment: I have the privileges I need. Execute, Read, and Write.

Comment: @Littlefoot - Are you going to add that as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Logfile isn't specified, so - by default - it resides in the same directory as the data file.

However, as you **write** to log file, you require **write** privilege on the MYDIR directory. Info you posted suggests that you have only READ privilege so - grant WRITE as well.